# What's the difference between resize and pyrDown/pyrUp in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am new to OpenCV and wondering what's the difference between `resize()` and `pyrDown()`/`pyrUp()`, and how to choose between them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cvPyrDown vs cvResize for face detection optimization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412756/cvpyrdown-vs-cvresize-for-face-detection-optimization)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`pyrDown()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?cv2.pyrUp#pyrdown) and [`pyrUp()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?cv2.pyrUp#pyrup) are used for building pyramids.

> `pyrDown()`*... performs the downsampling step of the Gaussian pyramid construction. First, it convolves the source image with [a] kernel [... then] it downsamples the image by rejecting even rows and columns.*

and

> `pyrUp()`*...performs the upsampling step of the Gaussian pyramid construction... First, it upsamples the source image by injecting even zero rows and columns and then convolves the result with the same kernel as in pyrDown() multiplied by 4.*

up/down-sampling is essentially like *nearest-neighbor* resizing.

`resize()` is used for resizing with various interpolation modes.